# PHP Autoloader Function - still need require_once?

Tags: php, class, autoloader

I'm getting my head around PHP autoloader. If I have the code below:

```
  function __autoload($class) {require_once('scripts/classes/' . $class . '.class.php');}
```

so long as my classes are named to fit the path above should I still need to use require_once

```
  require_once('scripts/classes/session.class.php');
```

Note: I'm including the __autoloading in the header() of the site (first page that is loaded. Do I need to include it on each page that is loaded to get its functionality to work? I would assume yes but I'm unsure...

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `__autoload`, or call `spl_autoload_register`, on every page loaded in the browser. So if all your pages use the same "header", putting it in there is enough.

Once you've done that, you never need to use `include` or `require` anywhere else: just mention the class `Session`, and PHP will use your autoload function to find the definition if it doesn't know it yet.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should use `include()`. The class will be included **only** once when it is not already loaded:

From the PHP manual:

> You may define an __autoload() function which is automatically called
>   in case you are trying to use a class/interface which hasn't been
>   defined yet.

And no, you can include the autoloader function just once in the entire application.

Also it is good practice to use [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this file in start of script and then just set a directory level 
instead of this constant: `WP_CONTENT_DIR`
This will automatically includes any file that it needs

```
<?php

class autoload
{

    private static function updatePhpFiles($dir_level, $php_files_json_name)
    {
        /**Get all files and directory using iterator.*/
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir_level));
        $filePaths = array();

        /**Get all php files in this directory level.*/
        foreach ($iterator as $path) {
            if (is_string(strval($path)) and pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php') {
                $filePaths[] = strval($path);
            }
        }

        /**Encode and save php files dir in a local json file */
        $fileOpen = fopen($dir_level . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $php_files_json_name, 'w');
        fwrite($fileOpen, json_encode($filePaths));
        fclose($fileOpen);
    }

    private static function includeMatchingFiles($dir_level, $php_files_json_name, $class_file_name)
    {
        $files = json_decode(file_get_contents($dir_level . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $php_files_json_name), true);
        $inc_is_done = false;

        /**Include matching files here.*/
        foreach ($files as $path) {
            if (stripos($path, $class_file_name)) {
                require_once $path;
                $inc_is_done = true;
            }
        }
        return $inc_is_done;
    }

    public static function include_system_files($dir_level, $class_name)
    {
        $php_files_json = 'phpfiles.json';
        $class_file_name = $class_name . '.php';

        /**Include required php files.*/
        if (is_file($dir_level . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $php_files_json)) {

            if (self::includeMatchingFiles($dir_level,$php_files_json, $class_file_name)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                self::updatePhpFiles($dir_level, $php_files_json);
                return self::includeMatchingFiles($dir_level, $php_files_json, $class_file_name);
            }

        } else {

            self::updatePhpFiles($dir_level, $php_files_json);
            return self::includeMatchingFiles($dir_level, $php_files_json, $class_file_name);

        }

    }

}

/**
 * Register autoloader.
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    autoload::include_system_files(WP_CONTENT_DIR, $className);
});
```